# How to retrieve all menu options

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am using react to produce a menu of options and currently I am only able to retrieve the last created menu option. Note that I am creating the options via looping, so this must be logic in my loop. Any advice will help.

```
var FilterMenu = React.createClass({
handleUserInput: function(filterText, selectedOption){
    this.props.onUserInput(filterText, selectedOption);
},
render: function(){
    return (
        <div className="FilterMenu">
            <FilterViews/>
            <FilterItems
                filterText={this.props.filterText}
                selectedOptions={this.props.selectedOptions}
                onUserInput={this.handleUserInput}
            />
        </div>
        )
}
});
var FilterViews = React.createClass({
    render: function(){
        return (<div className="FilterViews"></div>)
    }
});


var FilterItems = React.createClass({
    loadFiltersFromServer: function(){
        ajaxServerRequest().then(fulfilled);
        var self = this;
        function fulfilled(response){
            var filters = Object.keys(response[0]);
            filters.length = 10;
            self.setState({filters:filters});
        }
    },
    getInitialState: function(){ //these are filters being loaded, not selected
        return {filters:[]};
    },
    componentDidMount: function(){
        this.loadFiltersFromServer();
    },
    handleChange: function(){
        console.log('!!!145 - filter return',
                    this.refs.filterName.getDOMNode().innerText,
                    this.refs.filterOptionsInput.getDOMNode().value,
                    this.refs.filterTextInput.getDOMNode().value);

        this.props.onUserInput(
            this.refs.filterTextInput.getDOMNode().value,
            this.refs.filterOptionsInput.getDOMNode().value
        );
    },
    render: function(){
        var self = this;
        //console.log('FilterItems.this.props',this.props);
        //var Cost = [].push(<option>{filter.slice(5,filter.length)}</option>);
        var Cost = AppartmentCostRange.map(function(cost,index){
            return( <option value={cost} ref="filterOptionsInput" key={index}>
                        {cost}
                    </option>)
        });

        var FilterItems = this.state.filters.map(function(filter, index){
            return (
                <div>
                    <span value={filter} ref="filterName" key={index}>{filter}</span>
                    <select>

                        {Cost}
                    </select>
                </div>
                )
        });

        return (
            <div className="FilterItems">
                <h3>Filter Items</h3>
                    Quick Search
                    <input
                        type="text"
                        placeholder="search.."
                        value={this.props.filterText}
                        ref="filterTextInput"
                        onChange={this.handleChange}
                    />
                    <div onChange={this.handleChange}>
                        {FilterItems}
                    </div>
            </div>
            )
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this component is trying to do too much. Split it up

FilteredList
ListItem
CostSelector

you can generate the cost map data once and pass it to the CostSelector that each ListItem will have attached.

Currently you're passing one set of {Costs} to each options and react thinks it's just the one set of options. Wrap the whole select in a component and just pass the properties to it.